# Pouchdb and Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter on ionic: is it possible?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb, cordova-sqlite-storage, sqlite-cipher

I'd like to know if the following configuration is even possible for a hybrid app using ionic (angular) framework:

- [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)
- [cordova-sqlcipher-adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter)
- [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html)

This should work if we use the cordova-sqlite-plugin using a pouch db adapter, [pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite), but it doesn't with the encrypted one.

The problem I face is that typescript doesn't transpile. I don't know how to set up the environment and define a sqlite-cipher database with a key.

Here's some sample typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

import cordovaSqlitePlugin from 'pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.setUpPouch();
  }

  setUpPouch(){
    PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
    let db = new PouchDB('dummypouch.db', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite', key:"dummy_key"});
  }

}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to pass the key to the PouchDB adapter without breaking transpilation.

The line that makes transpiling fail:

```
let db = new PouchDB('dummypouch.db', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite', key:"dummy_key"});
```

The typescript transpile fails with this message:

```
[12:35:30]  typescript: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 21 
            Argument of type '{ adapter: string; key: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 
            'DatabaseConfiguration'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'key' does not exist in type 
            'DatabaseConfiguration'. 


      L20:    PouchDB.plugin(cordovaSqlitePlugin);
      L21:    let db = new PouchDB('dummypouch.db', { adapter: 'cordova-sqlite', key:"dummy_key"});

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/Users/santi/dummy_project/dummy_push_test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /Users/santi/dummy_project/dummy_push_test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at transpileWorker (/Users/santi/dummy_project/dummy_push_test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (/Users/santi/dummy_project/dummy_push_test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
    at /Users/santi/dummy_project/dummy_push_test/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:109:82
[12:35:30]  copy finished in 2.47 s
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question for reference.
Yes it is possible as long as we don't use the [@types/pouchdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pouchdb) module that adds types to typescript.

In case we have them we have to remove it and fix everything to work without typing in the related variables:

```
npm uninstall --save @types/pouchdb
```

Another option, I guess, is to write the proper types and include them in the project... I didn't do it so I am not certain.